# What is the point of format specifier in C?

Tags: c, integer, point, format-specifiers

What is the point of format specifier in C if we have allready set the type of variable before printf?

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=7
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Like, it's allready stated what a is, it's integer(int). So what is the point of adding %d to specify that it's an integer?

Comment: How would `printf` know about the type you passed to the function?

Comment: How do you expect the called function, `printf`, to know what type the argument is?  Also, format specifiers do more than just specify the argument type, but even if they didn't, they'd still be needed to know how to access its arguments.

Comment: Here's an exercise for you that will allow you to answer your own question:  Write your own version of `printf` that doesn't require a format string, but which can handle any number of arguments of type `int`, `double`, or `char *`.  You won't be able to do it, for the reasons I just gave.

Comment: Read about `%d`, `%o` and `%x`, all of which can be used to print an integer's value. It's convenient to have what is likely the most commonly used standard library function be as capable as it is. (Clue: C doesn't provide a separate "octal" or "hexadecimal" datatype.)

Comment: @TomKarzes Given : "doesn't require a format string, but which can handle any number of arguments ...", does [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) count?

Comment: There was a comment someone posted that answered my question, but it's deleted now. I didn't know that printf didn't have information about the type of variable. I'm new to programming and I am learning according to the book, I have googled my question and couldn't find clear answer. I have programmed a little bit in python and there wasn't need to specify type of variable once, much less twice. I appreciate every help, thank you.

Comment: FYI: In the case of strings, the library offers `puts()` (a simple version of `fputs()`) that simply outputs what it is given (appending a '\n' in the simple version). No formatting added.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's trying to solve a similar problem, but the arguments need to be wrapped in an elaborate `GP()` macro, with the caller putting them in a format that the print function can handle, so I'd say it doesn't count.  It is interesting though.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I posted this question is that it's weird to me that printf knows that a=7 but does not know that a is int. Both of which were stated in previous line. Maybe better question would be, how it knows that a=7 then?

Comment: @jeaq `printf` doesn't know anything about `a`, which is a local variable in the caller. All it knows is that the second argument is an `int` (as indicated by the format string), and after it extracts that argument, it knows it has the value `7`. That's all it knows. There's no quantum entanglement taking place.  Try to understand that `printf` is just a function that's being called.  The compiler isn't custom-building a different version of it for each call.  There's only one.

Comment: I think this is actually quite a good question.  If you're not steeped in C's ancient history, or if you're used to any number of languages with a built-in `print` statement, it's quite strange that C's `printf` function has the strange requirements that it does, and the more so if you haven't realized that `printf` is in fact an ordinary function.

Comment: It's only there to keep newbies occupied with pointless busy-work, troubleshooting conversion specifier bugs :) In a professional setting, `stdio.h` is rarely used for anything but sloppy debug code and not in production. Most people moved on to GUI programs over consoles some 25 years back.

Comment: @Lundin That's your opinion and you're entitled to it, but I'm a professional C and C++ programmer who still uses `printf` almost every day.  [*Chacun à son goût*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chacun_%C3%A0_son_go%C3%BBt).

Comment: @SteveSummit My condolences. And yeah I'm maintaining my fair share of old code too, lots of it with bad practices and many of them written by myself at some point. [Qui sine peccato est, primam lapidem mittat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_him_who_is_without_sin_cast_the_first_stone).

Comment: @Lundin It really depends on the end-user and their needs.  Sure, for interactive applications, especially those used by non-technical people, or just something that you want people to be able to use without having to read a manual, a GUI is the way to go.  But a lot of the time I have complex layers of scripts and filters that are more powerful and flexible than can be achieved by a simple interactive GUI.  For those, a command-line interface invoked by shell scripts and makefiles is clearly the way to go.  I generate entire sets of web pages that way.

Comment: @TomKarzes You can use command-line arguments without using stdio.h just fine.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but when writing a simple filter, or just something that reads or writes a file, stdio is usually the best way to do it.  If you don't need formatted I/O, you can just use `fread` and `fwrite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question really only makes sense in the context of C's history.

C is, by now, a pretty old language.  Though undoubtedly a "high level language", it is famously low-level as high-level languages go.  And its earliest compiler was deliberately and self-consciously small and simple.

In its first incarnation, C *did not enforce* type safety during function calls.  For example, if you called `sqrt(144)`, you got the wrong answer, because `sqrt` expects an argument of type `double`, but `144` is an `int`.  It was the programmer's responsibility to call a function with arguments of the correct types: the compiler did not know (did not even attempt to keep track of) the arguments expected by each function, so it did not and could not perform automatic conversions.  (A separate program, [`lint`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)), could check that functions were called with the correct arguments.)

C++ corrected this deficiency, by introducing the *function prototype*.  These were inherited by C in the first ANSI C standard in 1989.  However, a function prototype only works for a function that expects a single, fixed argument list, meaning that it can't help for functions that accept a variable number of arguments, the premier example being: `printf`.

The other thing to remember is that, in C, `printf` is a more or less ordinary function.  ("Ordinary" other than accepting a variable number of arguments, that is.)  So the compiler has no direct mechanism to notice the types of the arguments and make that list of types available to printf.  `printf` has no way of knowing, at run time, what types were passed during any given call; it can only rely (it must rely) on the clues provided in the format string.  (This is by contrast to languages, many of them, where the `print` statement is an explicit part of the language parsed by the compiler, meaning that the compiler can do whatever it needs to do in order to treat each argument properly according to its known type.)

So, by the rules of the language (which are constrained by backwards compatibility and the history of the language), the compiler can't do anything special with the arguments in a `printf` call, other than performing what is called the *default argument promotions*.  So the compiler can't fix things (can't perform the "correct" implicit conversion) if you write something like

```
int a = 7;
printf("%f", a);
```

This is, admittedly, an uncomfortable situation.  These days, programmers are used to the protections and the implicit promotions provided for by function prototypes.  If, these days, you can call

```
int x = sqrt(144);
```

and have the right thing happen, why can't you similarly call

```
printf("%f\n", 144);
```

Well, you can't, although a good, modern compiler will try to help you out anyway.  Although the compiler doesn't have to inspect the format string (because that's `printf`'s job to do, at run time), and the compiler isn't allowed to insert any implicit conversions (other than the default promotions, which don't help here), a compiler *can* duplicate `printf`'s logic, inspect the format string, and issue strong warnings if the programmer makes a mistake.  For example, given

```
printf("%f\n", 144);
```

gcc prints "warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int", and clang prints "warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int'".

In my opinion, this is a fine compromise, balancing C's legacy behavior with modern expectations.

Comment: "C++ corrected this deficiency, by introducing the function prototype. These were inherited by C in the first ANSI C standard in 1989" --> minor quibble, prior to C89  prototyping was coming into vogue, yet I do not recall it being an inheritance _from_  C++ as much it was a general C improvement.  The first C++ "compiler" I used was a translator of C++ into C and then compilation.  The C compiler at that time already had prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` accepts a variable number of arguments.  To process those variable arguments it (`va_start()`) needs to know the last fixed argument is.  It (`va_arg()`) also needs to know the type of each argument so it figure how much data to read.

The format specifier is also a compact template (or DSL) to express how text and variables should be formatted including field width, alignment, precision, encoding.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I posted this question is that it's weird to me that printf knows that a=7 but does not know that a is int. Both of which were stated in previous line. Maybe better question would be, how it knows that a=7 then?

Comment: @jeaq — it knows because you specify in the format string that the type of the second argument is `int`, so it pulls an `int` out of the variable argument list and formats that, and that value happens to be 7.  In advance, it doesn't know that the value is 7; it finds that it is 7 when it looks.  Roughly like `sqrt(4.0)` doesn't know in advance that the value is `4.0`; it pops the value off the stack and calculates with it.  If you're so minded, you could compare C's `printf()` family with Pascal's `writeln`, Fortran (77, 66) and its WRITE statement, and any other language with I/O support.

Comment: @jeaq I think this has been well answered by now, but `printf` does *not* know that `a` is an `int`.  The *compiler* knows, but it has no way to pass that information to `printf`.  As in any function call, only values are passed.  And in just about any ABI (this is even more true today than it once was), if a function tries to access a passed argument using a different type than the one actually passed, you get meaningless results.

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone. It's basically like this: we specify in printf what type of data  we want to print, an integer, and then printf goes to integers and finds variable named a and prints it.

Comment: I guess what bothered me was that I was thinking that once we use variable(in this case a) that that is it. no more a variable. But haven't thought about the fact we can have  variable(a) in float for example.

Comment: @jeaq `printf` does not "goes to integers and finds variable named `a`".  `printf` has no knowledge of, no visibility into, the variables in its caller (your `main` function).  If you call `printf("%d %f %d", …)`, what `printf` does is: (1) Fetch the first `int` value that was passed to it.  (2) Fetch the first `double` that was passed to it. (3) Fetch the second `int` that was passed to it.

Comment: (cont'd) It's not specified whether there are separate lists of `int`s and `double`s being passed, or whether they're all mushed together in one list somehow.  There are mechanisms that work either way, and they do work, as long as what you actually pass matches what `printf` expects (based on what you actually specify in the format string).  But if things don't match, they break down in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the point of adding `%d` to specify that it's an integer?

`printf()` is a function which **receives** a variable number of arguments of various type after the *format* argument.  It does not directly know the number nor the type of arguments passed nor received.

The callers knows the argument count and types it gives to `printf()`.

To pass the arguments count and type information, the *format* argument is used by the caller to encodes the argument count and types.  `printf()` uses that format and decodes it to know the argument count and type.  It is *very important* that the format and following arguments passed are consistent.